# counting numbers between two zeros

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector, say:

```
x <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
```

and I would like to obtain a vector that sums the values that falls between two zeros, i.e. the output should look like:

```
y = c(1,2,4,1,1,1)
```

Note that all ones should have zero at the beginning and zero at the end, otherwise it will not be counted. so the string 01010 only produce 1.

I tried to use run length with an index of zeros.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you asking for someone to right the script for you?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `y = (1,2,4,2,1,1,1,1)`? Otherwise, I'm missing what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should include an example of what you have tried already, and why this didn't work.

Comment: Should `0101010` be grouped as `010` `1` `010` or `01` `010` `10` -- and why?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, the first provided example suggests the clusters are created as you read from left to right. So the answer to your example would be `c(1, 1)`.

Comment: @flodel Yes, it does suggest that.  But I'm wondering if the problem is well-defined.

Comment: it is well-defined if the OP clarifies that you read from left to right, which the examples suggest.

Comment: Thank you all, i put my code but i did not show up in the slide. anyway, i am trying to calculate the rewards of ergodic Markov chain using the regenerative property of MC. So i am summing the rewards between two occurrences of 0s provided the rewards have distinct 0 at the beginning and distinct 0 at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sum.between.zeroes <- function(x) {
  library(stringr)
  x.str <- paste(x, collapse = "")
  nchar(str_extract_all(x.str, "01+0")[[1]]) - 2L
}

sum.between.zeroes(c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))
# [1] 1 2 4 1 1 1

sum.between.zeroes(c(0,1,0,1,0))
# [1] 1

sum.between.zeroes(c(1,1))
# integer(0)
```

---

If you want to remain within the base package, you can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
sum.between.zeroes <- function(x) {
  x.str <- paste(x, collapse = "")
  nchar(regmatches(x.str, gregexpr("01+0", x.str))[[1]]) - 2L
}
```

Comment: Nice. Stringr was my first port of call for this as well.